# SQL - Select only records where field contains either a given string explicitly OR or a range of strings within which given string falls

Tags: sql, excel, vba, substring, ibm-midrange

My data is set up as follows:
[MyDataFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGFwv.png)
This is just a sample. There are hundreds of rows.
This is for costing options (optional features) on a boat. My data above is a small sample of what we call an "optional parts kit". Column one contains the generic boat part number. Column 2 contains optional component part numbers that are tied to the generic boat by what we call "property conditions". These property conditions are in column 3. For instance, a boat can come with many different trolling motors or without a trolling motor at all. Property name for trolling motor here is TMP. This TMP property can have many values (each tied to a specific trolling motor). Currently, when I am costing a specific trolling motor option, say TMP='MK216', I have to manually select/find all components that are tied to this condition. In other words, select all rows where "Condition" column contains TMP(*E)='MK216' either explicitly or implicitly. By implicitly I mean that "Condition" column can specify a RANGE of trolling motor property values (i.e. (TMP(*E)>='MK214' AND TMP(*E)<='MK346') OR TMP(*E)='GM300' OR TMP(*E)='GM301' OR TMP(*E)='LW300')) that contains my value of interest 'MK216'. It is easy to find all rows containing a specific string. But I have no idea how to go about testing whether a component is tied to a RANGE of trolling motor values and whether 'MK216' falls within this range? What would be ideal is to write an SQL query that can pull all components tied to a given property/property value and then adds up the cost of each component to get the total cost of the optional feature.

Below is my code for selecting all rows where "condition" column contains  a specific string. Selected fields are as follows: pspmrn = Parent Part #, pscmrn = Component Part #, imdsc = Description, pscond = Condition, numqty = Qty, and imlcos = Cost.

Code is written in Excel VBA editor and database is IBM i AS/400. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    Cmd.CommandText =
       "create table qtemp.testIB as (                                                                
        With temp as (                                                                                  
        SELECT *                                                                                        
        FROM k23400t.Fcpstus)                                                                           
        SELECT pspmrn,pscmrn,imdsc,pscond,numqty,imlcos FROM temp                                       
        WHERE pspmrn = '23NZ19' AND (pscond like '%MK216%' OR pscond      
        LIKE '%TMP(*E)>=% AND TMP(*E)<=%')
        ORDER BY pscond                                                                                 
        ) WITH DATA"
```

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from your data format and edit it into your question.

Comment: Do you have in house developers?  I suspect that they already have a function you could call to validate the match.

Comment: We do have developers, but there is currently no AS/400 program that accomplishes this, which is why we do costing in this rather primitive way. I know that a developer could create a new screen/program that can do that, but I would have to put in a ticket which would be the lowest priority possible, meaning that it could take 6 months or longer until they could get to it.. I'm thinking there has to be a function in the AS/400, however, although probably written in RPGLE, buried somewhere in the "create specific part number" screen/program.

Comment: The "create specific part number" screen runs a program that creates a specific what we call "dot" number from the generic one ( i.e. 23NZ19 = generic, 23NZ19.101 = specific). This program, obviously, has to go through the optional parts kit data and test the conditioning against selected property values for this specific boat. The cost of the specific part nr/boat is in the system (automatically calculated when creating the part nr). However, there is nothing in the AS/400 that gives me the cost for each individual boat option.

Comment: I need to cost options individually because they are priced individually and published on price pages.

Comment: @Charles see my comments above. I don't expect anyone to just do the work for me, but I was wondering if I could get some help in terms of how to approach this problem. I know it's basically going to involve a lot of string manipulation. What built-in functions, if any, would work best for this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Charles I'm wondering if the conditioning in the condition column is simply a condition/input in a WHERE clause within the IBM i "specific item create" program.

Comment: Definitely not an SQL WHERE.  Possibly something in CL based upon the usage of `¬=` which is an old-school "not equal" modern version is `*NE` .